# AUC and Balanced accuracy in R Modelling

Tags: r, modeling, accuracy

Can someone please explain the difference between AUC(Area under curve) and balanced accuracy in R?

For eg: In decision tree modelling I got the,

AUC : 0.91

balanced accuracy : 0.72

please explain how to interpret or understand this model based on the above two accuracy values?

Answer (score 6):

AUC is not the same kind of  measure as accuracy.

AUC is area under curve for the ROC chart and it has also a meaning in the rank order statistics.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Area-under-curve_.28AUC.29_statistic_for_ROC_curves

Accuracy is simply a fraction of correctly predicted positives to all positives.

Suppose you have a data set with binary target variable where positive cases are 90% of all cases. Then you can simply classify everything to belong to positive cases and you will get accuracy of 90%.

Balanced accuracy is discussed here on page 2.

http://ong-home.my/papers/brodersen10post-balacc.pdf

I